# How does iCal / WebDev Calendar works?

Tags: webdav, icalendar

I tried to post in [Apple Developer Forum](https://devforums.apple.com/message/284244) but I got no luck for 6 days... I hope I get more here :)

I'm about to create a convert tool from a CRM application to ical format, **witch works fine** (I generate the correct code and is well imported, but I need more...), I wanted to know how does iCal App in the Mobile works.

> How, after the first subscription, does the calendar "refresh" works?

when I change the file in the server, how can I PUSH the changes to the device? how long in long time does iCal checks the file on the server?

on the Mac there is a Refresh Rate that we can set up, but not on the iPhone (at least not on mine 3G with iOS 4.01).

[image]

Can anyone point me into the **right track** to know more about the sync procedures between the device and the ics file on the server? **And How can I have both ways read/write**, what do I need to have in my end (the one that have the ics file) to **receive updates**?

**Thank** you!